# How can I filter values from table to use them at dropdown control?

Tags: php, html, laravel, voyager

I'm trying to use local scopes to filter select options. I found this document [Using local scopes with Voyager](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/bread/relationships#scoping-relationships). It says you can use functions called scopes at my model and specify those functions at my relationship's options, so that's what I did, but it doesn´t work.

My Model is

```
class Materiale extends Model
```

{
protected $fillable = [
'id',
'nombre',
'precio_mt',
'tipo'

```
];

public function scopeSustrato($query)
{
    return $query->where('tipo', 'SUSTRATO');
}

public function scopeAcabado($query)
{
    return $query->where('tipo', 'ACABADO');
}

public function scopeOtro($query)
{
    return $query->where('tipo', 'OTRO');
}
```

}

and my Relationship options are

[image]

As you can see at the picture, there I'm using

```
{
"scope": "acabado"
```

}

I tested The scope with the model directly and it works. So what's happening? Is it a bug of voyager?? I have 1.3.1 installed.

Can you give me a clue? Right now nothing happens, not even an error...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.
Just upgrade voyager 1.3.1 to 1.4.2 the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this?

{
"scope": "acabado",
}

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually, as you can see at the image, the quotation marks are included. The semicolon is not allowed by voyager, it send me an error message. Is it supposed that this should work? I mean local scopes with voyager?